# command to grep for multiple files?

Tags: file, grep

without having to write a shell script, I'm wondering if there's a way to list files based on a match to more than one criteria?

I know I can do:

```
ls ./files/ | grep samp
```

to get a list of all files that contain "samp" in the filename... But, is there a way to say, "list all of the files that match "samp" *or* "examp"?

I already figured out that

```
ls ./files/ | grep samp examp
```

doesn't work...

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) - it's much more powerful for doing this kind of thing, e.g.:

```
find ./files -name \*samp\* -o -name \*examp\*
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `|`:

```
ls ./files/ | grep -E 'samp|examp'
```

The `-E` is to allow the use of extended (modern) regular expressions.  If your version of `grep` doesn't support that behaviour, you'll need to escape the `|`:

```
ls ./file/ | grep 'samp\|examp'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls ./files/ | grep -esamp -eexamp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` command.

```
find ./files -name \*samp\* -o -name \*examp\*
```

The `-o` means "or". You can use `-iname` instead of `-name` for case-insensitive matching.